# Adding Web Reference to Script Task makes the SSIS package invalid.

Tags: ssis-2012

Web Reference makes the SSIS package invalid.

Within my SSIS package-controlflow I have a script component and within this component whenever I add a Web reference and close editor, script component gives me "Validation error. Control Flow Task Script Component: The binary code for the script is not found. 
Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully."

I can successfully build from the editor, but error resides there.
I have search lots of post and sites but haven't find a working solution.
Can someone help me solve this problem.

Ps: I am using SSMS 2012, SSDT for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Is the Validation Error when you run the package in debug? Or does it appear as soon as you close the editor?

Comment: Hi Mark, As soon as I close the editor the validation error appears.